# How to create own Ubuntu/linux snap/tools - Like Automute on Mac os

Tags: snap, tools

I would like to start building my own addons/tools/snaps for Ubuntu. But I have no idea where to start and in which programming language they are build. Could you help me in the right direction?

I would like to create tools like [Spectacle](https://github.com/eczarny/spectacle) and [AutoMute (for Mac)](https://github.com/yonilevy/automute) for Ubuntu.

Comment: It's usually not a matter of learning a *programming language*. It's usually about learning which applications (or stacks of applications) you must interact with. For audio, the place to start is learning how Pulseaudio ([wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PulseAudio)) ([upstream](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/)) works.

Comment: Here's the page you probably need most: https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/Developer/Clients/WritingVolumeControlUIs/

Answer (score 2):

I wrote Automute, flattered by the mention! To your question, both the apps in question have two parts: (1) Very simple UI and (2) Some "lower level" interface to the OS. In MacOS's case, it makes sense then to write them in Objective-C (or now Swift), as that's the platform's native language that allows to do both pretty easily.

If you're new to programming, I'd look into python as a good first language that [has libraries](https://pypi.org/project/pulsectl/) (which themselves were written in platform native language such as C) that would allow you to interface the OS, as well as [other libraries](https://wxpython.org/) letting you build simple UIs.

If you're already familiar with programming and want to learn the language in which complex instances of such applications are built, in the linux world that would probably be C++.

Good luck!

Comment: Awesome that you replied!!! :) Love your AutoMute application for Mac.
I have experience with Javascript and PHP. I am going to look into both C++ and Python. But probably first start with Python, because I am also new to creating snaps for Linux. Thanks for linking the Python library.

Answer (score 1):

Start at https://snapcraft.io/first-snap which provides assistance for multiple programming languages. There's also a [Forum](https://forum.snapcraft.io/categories) to ask questions if, after reading the [documentation](https://snapcraft.io/docs), you still need help.